# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Flask deployment

Tags: python, flask, deployment, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to set a Flask application in AWS EB and I am running on this issue on the Log.

`Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'app'.`

My application is using Application factory, so the init are set in the function.

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from .api.routes import api

    app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix="/api/v1")

    from .main import main

    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.run()
    return app
```

I have changed the WSGIPath to match my application name and object:

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    NumProcesses: '1'
    NumThreads: '15'
    WSGIPath: app
```

My application structure looks like this:

```
 __init__.py(empty)
 app.py
 main.py
 requirements.txt
 api/
     __init___.py (empty)
     routes.py
```

What am I missing ? I am feeling so close and so far away at the same time.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Elastic beanstalk expects your app.py to be named application.py. Also, change
`app = Flask(__name__)` to `application = app = Flask(__name__)`